# swift 3 with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, swift3

I am trying to make registration in swift3 with mysql 
but there is some thing wrong ,
when I run my app and make register return msg "some fields are empty"

In php code:

```
$fullname = htmlentities($_REQUEST["fullname"]);
$username = htmlentities($_REQUEST["username"]);
$email = htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_REQUEST["password"]);
$phone = htmlentities($_REQUEST["phone"])
```

swift code:

```
let  config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let  session = URLSession(configuration: config)
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/php/register.php?")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

let body = "fullname=\(FirstName.text)%20\(LastName.text)&username=\(UserName.text)&email=\(Email.text)&password=\(Password.text)&phone=\(Phone.text)"

request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in

if error != nil {
 print(error!.localizedDescription)

} else {

 do {

if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]

   {

 print(json)

    }

} catch {
     print("error in JSONSerialization")
     }     

   }      

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Please use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`, just a security tip; second could you log the `$_POST` on your php file : `file_put_contents('log.txt', json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` and give us what you get

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
```

replace `url` with `request`